# Cube root of $\omega$

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the cube root of $\omega$? where $\omega$ is the non-real cube root of $1$.

I got the cube root of $\omega$ in terms of $\omega$! I took cube root of $\omega$ as $x+iy$ then cubed it. I got an cubic relation between $x$ and $y$ which has root in terms of $\omega$.

This is not a standard problem from any book but I am curious to know the answer.

Comment: If $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$, then $\omega' = e^{2\pi i/9}$ is one number that has the property $\omega'^3 = \omega$. Generally, we have to be careful in complex numbers to call something *the* cube root of another complex number.

Comment: I for one would be curious to see *exactly* what your "cubic relation between $x$ and $y$" might be, and how it "has a root in terms of omega".  Seriously, I'm really curious about this, and if you posted your result it would save me the time trying to work it out for myself.  Thanks, and Cheers!

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Apart from $1$ there are two cube roots of$~1$, each with $3$ cube roots; the resulting set is known as that of the primitive $9$-th roots of unity. They are $\exp(2\pi\mathrm i\frac k9)$ for $k=1,2,4,5,7,8$, which you can express in trigonometric terms using Euler's formula.

Comment: Use the trigonometric form of a complex number

Comment: @Simon S.   In fact when I was trying to search exact value of sin20 I got that it was in terms of $w^\frac{1}{3}$ so I wanted to know the expression of cube root of omega in terms of $i$.

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria:  I made a few minor edits to your post to turn "omega" into $\omega$; hope it's OK.  In general, Greek letters may be $\LaTeX$ified by presenting them as, for example, \$\alpha\$, i.e., preceeded by a backslash and surrounded by "\$" signs.  Thus,  \$ \alpha \$ yields $\alpha$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to find the real and imaginary parts of a cube root of a complex number leads to cubic equations in other variables, both of which are intractable due to [CASUS irreducibilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis#Solution_in_non-real_radicals).

It is all very circular. Given an irreducible cubic, Cardano's method gives us an answer, but when the three (irrational ) roots are all real, the form of Cardano's involves the sum of the cube root of a complex number with the cube root of its complex conjugate. That particular piece of Cardano simply gives double the real part of that cube root. However, there is no way of separating out that number. Polar coordinate notation is a close as one gets, or numerical approximation.